# Connecting to SQL Server using NodeJS

Tags: sql-server, node.js, tedious

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server 2017 using Node. Here's my source code in NodeJS.

```
var express = require("express");
var Connection = require("tedious").Connection;
var path = require("path");
var config = {
    username: 'DBA',
    password: 'Password01',
    server: path.join("DESKTOP-N50AKSR","ONEJOHI"),
    options: { database: "users", encrypted: false }
};
var connection = new Connection(config);

var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    connection.on("connect", (err) => {
        console.log("Connected");
    })
    res.json({
        ok: true,
        message: "Hello World"
    })

})

app.listen(4040, () => {
    console.log("App running on 4040");
})
```

I have no Idea where I'm going wrong as connecting to my SQL Server using these same credentials is successful. Here are some screenshots. The first one shows the connection while the second one shows a successful connection.
[image: This shows connecting to the Database Engine]

[image: This shows a successful connection]

However, my NodeJS doesn't seem to work as I can't get it to print "Connected" to the console while accessing the default / route. It returns the JSON data but never logs anything to the console. I am confused as to where I'm going wrong. Any ideas...?

Comment: Are you sure path.join makes a backslash? On Linux, that'll be a forward slash. On windows, it's often two backslashes

Comment: Even if I switch to using "DESKTOP-RK05\ONEJOHI" it still doesn't work. And when logging out to console what the path.join creates, the string has a single slash.

Comment: Have you tried moving `connection.on("connect"` out of your get request? If there's no errors, then maybe it's actually working

Comment: Well what do you know! It works!! Thanks @cricket_007, I moved the connection.on() out of get and it works, lemme try querying some stuff and see if it works well.